# How can I capitalize one word in a UILabel in swift?

Tags: swift, uilabel

I am trying to make a dynamic UILabel like this:

> "I Love Watching The BBC"

As the label is dynamic, I will have no idea of its contents.
I can leave the text alone and let the user define what they want. I can capitalize the whole string, the first letter of each word, or all words in a string.

The problem is that when capitalizing, words that are entered as uppercase become lower case.

So, in the example above

> BBC

becomes

> Bbc

I've searched all over the web, and don't think there is a way to do this.

As requested, code so far:

```
cell.projectName?.text = projectNameArray[indexPath.row].localizedCapitalized
```

Comment: Could you demonstrate by showing your code?

Comment: Maybe: Separate each words (there are a few questions about that), and apply the uppercase choice if the initial one isn't full uppercase, then reconstruct the string.

Comment: I have possibly found an answer here: `https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string`. I'm checking.

Comment: I am quite confused as to what you are trying to do. What does `projectNameArray[indexPath.row]` contain? How is what's contained there different from what you want to show in the label?

Comment: So all you really need is a way to detect in advance any all-caps words? But that’s easy. They are the ones that don’t change when you uppercase them. So detect those and protect them from capitalization.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll try that.

Comment: Thanks Matt. That works fine. However, I decided to just let the user type the label and not play with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add this extension to your code.

```swift
extension String {
    func capitalizingFirstLetter() -> String {
        return prefix(1).capitalized + dropFirst()
    }

    mutating func capitalizeFirstLetter() {
        self = self.capitalizingFirstLetter()
    }
}
```

(Form [Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string))

Also for the `UILabel.text` property apply a custom function that split each word in string, and apply the capital letter.

An example could be that:

```swift
extension String {
    func capitalizeWords() -> String {
        self.split(separator: " ")
        .map({ String($0).capitalizingFirstLetter() })
        .joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
```

The complexity could be decreased I think, but it's just a working hint ;)